# In Dart, can you make web_ui build static html files like the web_ui library itself does?

Tags: dart, dart-webui

Ok, the question may sound a bit confusing, here's what I want to do:

I want to use the web-templating feature of web_ui to generate an html output, (would go into the "out" folder).

Maybe a more basic question would be, how do you use Dart's build feature, like what the web_ui library is doing (build stuff into the "out" folder)?

Answer (score 2):

I'm developing buildtool, which hosts build tasks for exactly this type of purpose. Check it out on github: https://github.com/dart-lang/buildtool/

Right now buildtool supports the Web UI compiler and dart2js and it's fairly easy to write your own tasks. We envision a lot more tasks like generating docs, fixing up URLs in HTML for deployment, generating AppCache manifest files, etc.

As for generating HTML, buildtool itself won't do that, but a task can. Web UI doesn't generate static HTML on the server, but there are a few template libraries out there that might be useful.

What kind of thing do you need to do specifically?

Comment: Can you explain, in a little more detail, the relationship between build.dart and buildtool? I think that will help.